# cannot compile cpp files under the python pyc script file

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to compile & execute my hw cpp file under the python script file which we are given by lecturer. the how-to-manual.pdf he sent us it says use:

```
c:\>python ./submit.pyc problemID -u username -p password -b //submit.pyc is already given to us
```

and here is the manifest.txt we are given:

```
[main]

problem = gc

build =
    g++ main.cpp -o solver

run =
    ./solver %f
```

my cpp file works normally like this:

```
./solver input_file
```

However, I am trying (I have to) to do this under the windows OS. I have Python 2.7.x installed and python.exe is in the Command `PATH`. I can't run it under the linux ssh sytem because there is 2.4.x python installed and I can't touch it (school's system).

Anyway, when I execute the line above, it returns me:

```
Command execution failed:
g++ solver.cpp -o solver
```

I think I told everything I can. So, any idea that what I have to do else? except asking to lecturer:)

Comment: is `g++` in the path?

Comment: @MatsPetersson No? Do I have to do it also? I thought the Python calls itself. I have mingw compiler under the code::blocks but.. ? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above to work it needs to be able to find g++ so you need to add the directory that it resides in to the PATH environment variable.  This can be done from within your python script or on the command line with:

```
path=Where\g++\lives;%path%
```

This will only apply within the current DOS session.

Or you can add it permanenty through `system settings->advanced settings->environmental variables`

You could also look at using a python virtual environments on the schools linux system.